# pkg-config has different output in (Centos 7 & Fedora 28) and Debian 9

Tags: pjsip, pkg-config

I'm working now with pjsip and found one problem. After installation this library we get following file ***libpjproject.pc***:

```
# Package Information for pkg-config
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=/usr/local/lib
includedir=/usr/local/include

Name: libpjproject
Description: Multimedia communication library
URL: http://www.pjsip.org
Version: 2.7.2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lpjsua2-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lstdc++ -lpjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjsip-ua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjsip-simple-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjsip-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-videodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjnath-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjlib-util-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  -lsrtp-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lresample-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lgsmcodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lspeex-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lilbccodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lg7221codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lyuv-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lwebrtc-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu  -lpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lssl -lcrypto -lm -lrt -lpthread  -lasound
Cflags: -I${includedir} -g -O2 -I/usr/local/include -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1
```

In RedHat compatible OSs I get following response on this command:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject
-lpjsua2 -lstdc++ -lpjsua -lpjsip-ua -lpjsip-simple -lpjsip -lpjmedia-codec -lpjmedia-videodev -lpjmedia-audiodev -lpjmedia -lpjnath -lpjlib-util -lwebrtc -lsrtp -lgsm -lspeex -lspeexdsp -lpj -lssl -lcrypto -luuid -lm -lrt -lpthread
```

due to this some library make cannot find.

In Debian 9 I see normal output on the same command:

```
-g -O2 -DPJ_AUTOCONF=1 -O2 -DPJ_IS_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DPJ_IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lpjsua2-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lstdc++ -lpjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjsip-ua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjsip-simple-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjsip-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-videodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjmedia-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjnath-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpjlib-util-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lsrtp-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lresample-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lgsmcodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lspeex-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lilbccodec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lg7221codec-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lyuv-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lwebrtc-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -lm -lrt -lpthread
```

My question is how to make output on CentOS & Fedora the same as Debian?
libpjproject.pc - absolutely the same on both OSes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, package config files - ***libpjproject.pc*** for different OSs don't have to be the same, since they are generated depending on system (and user) configuration. You didn't describe how did you get this file, because code repository contains only template for it : ***libpjproject.pc.in***. The ***libpjproject.pc*** is produced by make **install** target. So, my guess would be that you just copied it from one machine to another, however it should be generated.

So, the easiest way to get correct .pc files, is to install pjproject:

```
# Debian:
sudo apt-get install libpjproject-dev
# RedHat/Centos:
sudo yum install libpjproject-devel
```

Note that **pkg-config** disables by default in output default system flags and libs, so try:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS=1
$ export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject
```

[Here](https://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/28/x86_64/p/pkgconf-pkg-config-1.4.2-1.fc28.i686.html) I found that on Fedora 28 **pkg-config** is just a symlink to another similar tool [pkgconf](https://github.com/pkgconf/pkgconf) (what a confusion!). According to [source code](https://git.dereferenced.org/pkgconf/pkgconf/src/commit/f4137995d9a5f2c5647ff79961cb0c516923faa8/main.c) it should support these two environment variables, but also supports two command line options with the same effect, so try:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs --keep-system-cflags --keep-system-libs libpjproject
```

Comment: I just compiled it from source code then make install. It creates libpjproject.pc automatically. I did the same on both OSes. I didn't copy anything.

Comment: @YevgenyTaradayko OK, the key to you problem then lies in how did you configure before building. So, please include your command line $./configure <> and output, were there any warnings/errors?

Comment: @YevgenyTaradayko please also check my update about default flags

Comment: I used ./configure without any arguments. Only thing I did it's created user.mak with 
export CFLAGS += -fPIC -w
export LDFLAGS += -fPIC -w
then standard commands: ./configure, make dep, make, make  install

Comment: After add your suggested export variables I see include and lib folders. But still don't see other flags like -O2 and so on.

Comment: I tested on PROD env Centos 7. There it works perfectly. So problem seems in Fedora 28 only.

Comment: @YevgenTaradayko check my update, I had no idea about "clone" tool called pkgconf that is actually used on Fedora